# Get data each day if no record display zero

Tags: jquery, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, chart.js

Hi i'm trying to create query that will give me the employee double break count each day.
I need to display each day but what i able to display now is the only days that has value.

```
SELECT   shift, count (COUNT) AS COUNT, TRUNC (date_time) AS date_time
          FROM vw_break_time_doublebreak
         WHERE TRUNC (date_time) IN (
                  SELECT       TRUNC (TO_DATE ('2020-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
                                      'MM'
                                     )
                             + LEVEL
                             - 1 AS dateshift
                        FROM DUAL
                  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 31)

      GROUP BY shift, TRUNC (date_time)
      ORDER BY shift, date_time ASC;
```

result im getting

```
SHIFT   COUNT   DATE_TIME

R   11  1/1/2020
R   29  1/2/2020
R   22  1/3/2020
R   3   1/4/2020
R   32  1/6/2020
R   39  1/7/2020
R   41  1/8/2020
R   39  1/9/2020
R   44  1/10/2020
R   9   1/11/2020
R   1   1/12/2020
R   20  1/13/2020
R   29  1/14/2020
R   31  1/15/2020
R   28  1/16/2020
R   34  1/17/2020
R   7   1/18/2020
R   2   1/19/2020
R   33  1/20/2020
R   32  1/21/2020
R   26  1/22/2020
R   37  1/23/2020
R   32  1/24/2020
R   7   1/25/2020
R   41  1/27/2020
R   41  1/28/2020
R   28  1/29/2020
R   41  1/30/2020
R   30  1/31/2020
```

see result above there's no row for january 5 and january 26.

On the source view there's really no data on that date.

expected result

```
SHIFT   COUNT   DATE_TIME

    R   11  1/1/2020
    R   29  1/2/2020
    R   22  1/3/2020
    R   3   1/4/2020
    R   0   1/5/2020 <=
    R   32  1/6/2020
    R   39  1/7/2020
    R   41  1/8/2020
    R   39  1/9/2020
    R   44  1/10/2020
    R   9   1/11/2020
    R   1   1/12/2020
    R   20  1/13/2020
    R   29  1/14/2020
    R   31  1/15/2020
    R   28  1/16/2020
    R   34  1/17/2020
    R   7   1/18/2020
    R   2   1/19/2020
    R   33  1/20/2020
    R   32  1/21/2020
    R   26  1/22/2020
    R   37  1/23/2020
    R   32  1/24/2020
    R   7   1/25/2020
    R   0   1/26/2020 <=
    R   41  1/27/2020
    R   41  1/28/2020
    R   28  1/29/2020
    R   41  1/30/2020
    R   30  1/31/2020
```

**Note there is also other shift i only show the data on R shift**

data result will be use in graph using chart js
Hope someone help me out with this thank you.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the link provided in the closed remarks is pointing to another database and not oracle.

Comment: @Slkrasnodar it did not solve my problem, the table dont realy have data on that date unlike on the provided link

Comment: Unfortunately your question is closed which prevents me from posting a reply.

Comment: oww so how can i get help then

Comment: looks like query in invalid format whats with the with t (mnth)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209695/discussion-between-slkrasnodar-and-kiffer-van).